# Anchor tag of mega menu is not working in mobile version in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, megamenu

I have a `megamenu` in my laravel website. All the menu links are working properly in desktop version of the website.

But in mobile version no anchor tag links are working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-container">
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/clinic') }}">Clinic </a>             
       <ul>
        @foreach($_SESSION['clinic'] as $data)
          @foreach($_SESSION['all_clinic_with_services'] as $key=>$datum)
            @if($key === $data->id)
              <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic/'.str_slug($data->name, "-").'-'.$data->id ) }}">{{ $data->name }}</a>
                <ul>
                  @foreach($datum as $value)
                    <li><a href="#">{{ $value->name }}</a></li>
                  @endforeach
                </ul>
              </li>                    

            @else
              @continue;

            @endif

          @endforeach
        @endforeach

        @foreach($_SESSION['all_clinic_without_services'] as $data)
          <li><a href="{{ url('/clinic') }}">{{ $data->name }}</a>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/technology') }}">Technology</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/photo-gallery') }}">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/price-list') }}">Price List</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/video') }}">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/about-us') }}">About Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/message-from-MD') }}">Messaging from Managing Director</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/about-us') }}">About Laser Medical Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/medical-consultant') }}">Medical Consultant</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/medical-officer') }}">Medical Offficer</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/nutritionist') }}">Clinical Nutritionist</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/physiotherapist') }}">Physiotherapist</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/nurse') }}">Senior Staff Nurse</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/customer-service') }}">Customer Service</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/contact-us') }}">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**script**

```
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function () {

"use strict";

$('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
//Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


$('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
//Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

$(".menu > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

//Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
//Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
//Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
//Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

$(".menu > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
        $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
//If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

$(".menu > ul > li").click(function (e) {
    if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
        $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
//If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

$(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
    $(".menu > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
    e.preventDefault();
});
//when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)
});
```

Is it script related problem ?

Where to change? Someone Help me, please?

I have already post this issue in stackoverflow before but no answer got. That's why repost the issue again. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean those links `<li><a href="#">{{ $value->name }}</a></li>`?

Comment: @MoshFeu...no ... others .. like `<li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url('/technology') }}">Technology</a></li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because of the `e.preventDefault()`.

You can see in the example below that the first `li` has `event.preventDefault()` so the click on the link inside do nothing and the second works.

It's happening only on mobile because only on mobile (`if ($(window).width() <= 943) {`) you call the `preventDefault` on `click`.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="click-not-working"><a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Click is not working</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Click does work</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.click-not-working').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

https://jsbin.com/xugilaguku/edit?html,js,output

I'm not sure why you need this in the first place..

Comment: So where to change to solve it ? Should I remove `e.preventDefault();` from the script function?

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. It solves. comment out the  `e.preventDefault();` from the function where `$(window).width() <= 943` and it works !!!

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck!